# Custom deep copy implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, copy, iterable

I am trying to replicate the behavior of `copy.deepcopy`. I have a method with some very weird behavior.

```
def ReplicateIterable(i):
    try:
        if len(i) > 1:
            return [ReplicateIterable(e) for e in i]
        else:
            return i
    except TypeError:
        return i
```

This is my function. The `try` block is to catch non-iterables. I was getting some infinite recursion issues because strings are iterables and I am using characters as elements of my lists, so it checks if the iterable length is `>1` before recursing.

I get this behavior in a test case:

```
>>> State = [['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], []]
>>> TempState = ReplicateIterable(State)
>>> TempState
[['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], []]
>>> TempState[0].remove('c')
>>> TempState[1].append('c')
>>> State
[['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['c']]
>>> TempState
[['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], ['c']]
```

Apparently, `TempState[0]` ***does not*** point to `State[0]`, but `TempState[1]` ***does*** point to `State[1]`. `State[0]` was left unchanged by the `TempState[0].remove('c')` operation, but both `State[1]` and `TempState[1]` were modified by `TempState[1].append('c')`.

Why does this behavior occur? How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that any list shorter than two items is special-cased in your `ReplicateIterable` function, so new objects aren't created in these cases:

```
>>> l1 = [[], [0], [1, 2]]
>>> l2 = ReplicateIterable(l1)
>>> [i1 is i2 for i1, i2 in zip(l1, l2)]
[True, True, False]
```

Your comments in the question suggest that this was an attempt to avoid recursion issues with strings, but it isn't an appropriate way to do that. Instead, specifically special-case strings:

```
def replicate_iterable(iter):  # note style guide compliance
    """Deep copy the iterable."""
    if isinstance(iter, str):
        return iter
    try:
        return [replicate_iterable(item) for item in iter]
    except TypeError:
        return iter
```